# Travelling during weekends - Public transportation - Baltimore

Tags: usa, public-transport, weekends, baltimore

I'm living in Baltimore for a short period of time. I work a lot during the week (and don't really have time to organize my trips) and have free time in weekends.

I don't have a driving license here so I'd like to make short round-trip of 1 day or 2 using public transportation.

I was thinking about visiting DC, Philly, Ocean city and more!

What's the best way for me to reach these places? What else should I visit (something that will take less than 4 hours to reach)?

I'm more interested in some places where I can enjoy nature, relax etc than some busy cities where everyone is rushing!

Comment: If you were traveling on weekdays, the MARC train to DC is cheap, and DC metro is great for getting places. Otherwise there's Amtrak.

Comment: There is affordable intercity bus service between NYC and DC, Philadelphia, and Boston. I don't know for a fact, but I'd be very surprised if these buses don't also serve Baltimore.